# Getting Apache to redirect all urls to a different host

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

I would like to redirect all urls from the host a.myhost.com to b.myhost.com. I've explored all the options - Apache redirect, rewriterule directives. I want the redirects to happen to the same target url - which is http://b.myhost.com - regardless of what the original url was (e.g. a.myhost.com/a.html). All the examples that claim to be able to do this, actually don't, in practice (atleast on my Apache installation). The a.html is carried forward to the redirected host - which is not what is desired.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you possible tell if you have `<Directory />` in your httpd.conf or inside your `VirtualHost` with `AllowOverride` and what is it set to ? it may be the cause why your mod_rewrite inst working.

Answer (score 1):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName a.example.com
  RedirectMatch .*$ http://b.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://b.myhost.com/ [R,L]
```

Does that work?

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't - in fact, this is the most common example I've come across.

Answer (score 0):

I belive something like this would do the job

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a.example.com
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://b.example.com$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't. Am suspecting something with my Apache installation now.

Comment: @talonx then you don't have mod_rewrite enable at least.

Comment: Hmm...I checked - seems to be enabled.

Comment: what "seems to be enabled" means ? i am sorry but it is "yes, it is enabled" or "no, it is not". Have you looked into the httpd.conf file for the module load entry for mod_rewrite, have you check for the .ht entry aswell ? Can you update your answer with more information like how are you using the rules above, what and where the file is located etc ?

Comment: @Prix - sorry, my bad. It _is_ enabled. The LoadModule entry is present, and so is the .htaccess entry (I assume that's what you meant). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just making sure and pardon me if i sounded rude :) do you have any rules on your `.htaccess` besides the rules we asked you to try here (if you do can you update your question with the rules you have and where did u place the rules we asked you to try) ? is your `.htaccess` file located on the root directory (for example if your root directory is `/home/my_user/public_html` it would be `/home/my_user/public_html/.htaccess`) ?